# Dynamic JFrame, streged Objects

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When I create my dynamic JFrame and I add my objects, for example Buttons, I don't want them to be streged out, I want them to be resized by me. Is there any posible way to resize them?

Comment: Use an appropriate [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.